# Calling a php function in the handlebars template

Tags: php, handlebars.js

I know this code contains errors but can you explain clearly why such code  is forbidden in the template?

```
<script id="my_template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <p>some HTML here</p>
    <?=php_function("{{foreign_val}}")?>
    <p>some HTML here</p>
</script>
```

Comment: No, this is not possible, because PHP code (Server Side Code) is parsed before Client side code.

Comment: Why did I get -1? Because the answer is "No"? Or I should have known the answer before asking a question to prevent getting -1. Uffff. I think it's a valuable question and answer for some people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) is a JavaScript templating engine. JavaScript, not including things such as node.js, is a client-side scripting language that executes purely on the "client" (i.e. in a web browser).

PHP, on the other hand, is a server-side scripting language that executes on the "server".

In effect, they cannot execute one another. PHP can output JavaScript that the client then executes when the page loads. JavaScript can also make calls to a PHP page and read the response. However, neither can execute the other.

In your exact example, if the handlebars template you've provided is in a file that's PHP-executable (such as say `my_template.php`), the PHP `php_function()` would be called prior to sending the code to the client. However, it will be called with the raw `{{foreign_val}}` placeholder/token and not the template-replaced value that you'd probably hope for.

For this to work the way you'd want, you could have JavaScript make an ajax call to a server-side script with the value you want replaced and the PHP script would return the results of `php_function()` using that value and then you could populate your template accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This can't work because PHP has already done it's work by the time the page is rendered. 
Handlebars is a client side technology. All you will do is pass "{{foreign_val}}" to your PHP function.